# plax.js works only when reloading

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

ok, here is the code:

In HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" id="seccionCont10">
    <div id="seccionCont10texto" class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="contTextoNegro">Tus <p class="contTextoAzul contEnLinea">datos</p> siempre <p class="contTextoAzul contEnLinea">seguros</p></div>
        <div class="descripcionTextoCont">Con la mejor tecnología de Base de Datos SQL tus datos estarán siempre protegidos, también podrás respaldar tus datos desde Valery® Contabilidad.</div>
    </div>
    <img src="images/contabilidad/patronCont.png" id="patronCont" alt="">
    <img src="images/contabilidad/seccion10cont.png" id="candadoCont" alt="">
</div>
```

and the Jquery

```
$('#patronCont').plaxify({"xRange":200,"yRange":100});
    $.plax.enable({"activityTarget":$("#seccionCont10")});
```

Now, when I load for the first time, or I change to another partial and then go back to the partial where the plax.js is, it doesn't work, it doesn't move the background, I have to reload it.

Notice that I am using Angular to change between partials, it seems that when I switch the plugin doesn't run.... something happens when I reload that triggers it.

Now, I am new to Angular, and I just have no idea why this isn't working

**UPDATE**

The jquery code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){                       

        $('#patronCont').plaxify({"xRange":200,"yRange":100});
        $.plax.enable({"activityTarget":$("#seccionCont10")});
    }
});
```

I tried to get it triggered like this

```
        setTimeout( arro, 1000);
    function arro(){    
        $('#patronCont').plaxify({"xRange":200,"yRange":100});
        $.plax.enable({"activityTarget":$("#seccionCont10")});
    }
```

and it's not working either

Comment: Do you have your jquery in a document ready function?

Comment: @Aaron yes, It's all wrapped in   ´$(document).ready(function(){
});´

Answer (score 1):

Often when you have jQuery plugins that modify the DOM you want to create [angular directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for them which initialize and clean up after the feature.

Because of how plax works, requiring you to register (plaxify) images and then enable plax itself, you might achieve this with two directives, one for each action:

The markup would look something like:

```
<img class="plaxImg" xRange="200" yRange="100" src="/path/to/image1.png">
<img class="plaxImg" xRange="200" yRange="100" src="/path/to/image2.png">
<img class="plaxImg" xRange="200" yRange="100" src="/path/to/image3.png">

<!-- ...then then sometime later: -->
<plax activityTarget="#seccionCont10" />
```

And directives something like:

```
// a directive to `plaxify` images    
app.directive('plaxImg', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      $(elem).plaxify({"xRange": attrs.xRange, "yRange": attrs.yRange});
    }
  };
}]);

// and a drop in element directive to start plax
app.directive('plax', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      var args = {};

      if (attrs.activityTarget) {
        args.activityTarget = $(attrs.activityTarget);
      }

      // probably want to disable first to be sure that plax isn't already
      // initialized
      $.plax.disable();
      // then enable with the new args
      $.plax.enable(args);

      elem.on('destroy', function () {
        $.plax.disable();
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

Note this is rough and completely untested and probably not a drop in fix, but should give you a rough idea of how to wrap jQuery plugins with angular directives, and how to handle plax's use-case specifically.